# how to replace delimiter when delimiter also present in field data at any place in a file?

Tags: linux, csv, sed

I have content of input file in linux, something like

```
"test1",2,2,,0,"Sun,day",Jan
"be,st3",1,0,,0,"Sunday",Feb1
"nest",0,0,,0,"Sunday",Jul
"rest,5",,,,0,"Sunday",Aug
```

Need Output like

```
test1|2|2||0|Sun,day|Jan
be,st3|1|0||0|Sunday|Feb1
nest|0|0||0|Sunday|Jul
rest,5||||0|Sunday|Aug
```

used tr command to replace the , with |  it replaces the fieldvalue as well. I am not able to understand how to only change the delimiter not the values. can someone please provide some pointers how and which commands i can use to perform this task ?

Comment: you mean rest,5 in the last line...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks. corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a difficult task to achieve with `sed`.

In python (version 3.x), on the other hand, done with a few lines:

```
import csv

with open("input.csv") as fr:
    with open("output.csv","w",newline='') as fw:  # uncomment for python 3.x
    with open("output.csv","wb") as fw:            # python 2.x only
        cr = csv.reader(fr,delimiter=",")
        cw = csv.writer(fw,delimiter="|")
        cw.writerows(cr)
```

How it works: It just uses the amazing built-in `csv` module. read with a separator, write with another.

okay, now just for fun ... my `sed` solution if you really want to know

create a sedfile like this:

```
s/"\([^",]\+\)"/\1/g
s/"\([^"]\+\),\([^"]\+\)"/\1%\2/g
s/,/\|/g
s/%/,/g
```

apply it `sed -f sedfile.txt input.csv > output.csv`

how it works:

- strips the quotes from the simple fields
- strips the quotes from the fields containing commas, but replace commas by percent signs
- change the separator
- change back percent signs by comas

result:

```
test1|2|2||0|Sun,day|Jan
be,st3|1|0||0|Sunday|Feb1
nest|0|0||0|Sunday|Jul
rest,5||||0|Sunday|Aug
```

it's limited to 1 coma per protected field (can be extended to 3 or more...) and fields must not use the `%` sign.

Comment: Python 2.6.6 ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using sed:

```
$ sed -E ':a; s/^(([^"]*("[^"]*")?)*),/\1|/; ta; s/"//g' file
test1|2|2||0|Sun,day|Jan
be,st3|1|0||0|Sunday|Feb1
nest|0|0||0|Sunday|Jul
rest,5||||0|Sunday|Aug
```

#### How it works

This changes `,` to `|` if the `,` occurs after an even number of `"`.

- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `s/^(([^"]*("[^"]*")?)*),/\1|/`

  Starting from the beginning of the line, `^`, this looks for any number of the following sequence:

  ```
  1. `[^"]*`  = zero or more non-quotes

  2. `("[^"]*")?`  = pairs of quotes
  ```
- `ta`

  If the previous `s` command resulted in a successful substitution, then jump back to label `a` and try again.
- `s/"//g`

  After we have replaced all the unquoted commas with vertical bars, we remove the quotes.

#### Simplification

As potong points out, an alternative and simpler solution is:

```
sed -E 's/(([^,"]*("[^"]*")*)*),/\1|/g;s/"//g' file
```

This works because of two subtleties: (1) sed's regexes look for the left-most longest match, and (2) when doing a global (g) substitution, a subsequent match is not allowed to overlap the prior match.  With these two rules in mind, this command replaces `,` with `|` only after even numbers of quotes.

Comment: Could this be shortened to `sed -r 's/(([^,"]*("[^"]*")*)*),/\1|/g;s/"//g' file`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
"test1",2,2,,0,"Sun,day",Jan
"be,st3",1,0,,0,"Sunday",Feb1
"nest",0,0,,0,"Sunday",Jul
"rest,5",,,,0,"Sunday",Aug
xyz,"12,234","a,b","abc",893,23,"Sep"

$ perl -pe 's/"(?<a>[^"]+)",|(?<a>[^,]*),/$+{a}|/g' ip.txt 
test1|2|2||0|Sun,day|Jan
be,st3|1|0||0|Sunday|Feb1
nest|0|0||0|Sunday|Jul
rest,5||||0|Sunday|Aug
xyz|12,234|a,b|abc|893|23|"Sep"
```

- `"(?<a>[^"]+)",` text inside `""` (followed immediately by `,`) is captured inside named group `a`
- `(?<a>[^,]*),` text other than `,` ending with `,` is also captured inside named group `a`
- The named group is accessible via the hash `%+`
- The order is important - `"(?<a>[^"]+)",` is first finished before the alternate regex is evaluated
- **Note:** If final element is quoted, say `"Sep"`, the quotes won't be removed

**Further Reading:** [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) - search for `named capture`